# Accessing an Enum in Python

Tags: python, enums

How can I access an enum from another class - eg for class B as below:

```
from examples import A

class B:
    properties = A

    def __init__(self, name, area, properties):
        self.name = name
        self.area = area
        self.properties = properties

B.property = B("test", 142.43, A)
print ("B color: "+B.properties.color)
print ("A color: "+str(A.color._value_))

#in separate module
from enum import Enum

class A(Enum):
    color = "Red"
    opacity = 0.5

print("A color: "+str(A.color._value_))
```

When I run class A :

```
A color: Red
```

When I run class B:

```
    print ("B color: "+B.properties.color)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'color'
```

Comment: is `__init__` part of class `B` ?

Comment: So what is the module containing `A` *named*? Did you name it `A.py` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is the *module* containing your class, not the class itself. You'd have to reference the class in the module still:

```
from examples.A import A
```

or use

```
properties = A.A
```

and

```
print ("A color: "+str(A.A.color._value_))
```

Try to avoid using uppercase names for modules; the [Python style guide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) recommends you use *all lowercase* for module names. That way you won't so easily mix up modules and the classes contained in them.